# How to wrap around to the start/end of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d array with a different species in each one. I pick a random element on the array and I want to count up how many of each species are in the eight squares immediately adjacent to that element.

But I want the array to wrap at the edges, so if I pick an element on the top row, the bottom row will be counted as "adjacent". How can I do this while iterating through `j in range (x-1,x+1)` and the same for j and y?

Also, is there a more elegant way of omitting the element I originally picked while looking through the adjacent squares than the `if (j!=x or k!=y` line?

```
numspec = [0] * len(allspec)
for i in range (0,len(allspec)):
    #count up how many of species i there is in the immediate area
    for j in range(x-1,x+1):
        for k in range(y-1,y+1):
            if (j!=x or k!=y):
                numspec[hab[i][j]] = numspec[hab[i][j]]+1
```

Comment: You should consider using [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/).

Comment: To help you in your search, the name for the datatype you require is "toroidal grid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for wrapping, I would recomend using relative indexing from -1 to +1 and then computing real index using modulo operator (`%`).

As for making sure you don't count the original element (x, y), you are doing just fine (I would probably use reversed contidion and continue, but it doesn't matter).

I don't quite understand your usage of `i, j, k` indexes, so I'll just assume that `i` is index of the species, `j, k` are indexes into the 2d map called `hab` which I changed to `x_rel`, `y_rel` and `x_idx` and `y_idx` to make it more readable. If I'm mistaken, change the code or let me know.

I also took the liberty of doing some minor fixes:

- introduced `N` constant representing number of species
- changed `range` to `xrange` (xrange is faster, uses less memory, etc)
- no need to specify 0 in range (or xrange)
- instead of `X = X + 1` for increasing value, I used `+=` increment operator like this: `X += 1`

Here is resulting code:

```
N = len(allspec)
numspec = [0] * N
for i in xrange(N):
    for x_rel in xrange(-1, +1):
        for y_rel in xrange(-1, +1):
            x_idx = (x + xrel) % N
            y_idx = (y + yrel) % N
            if x_idx != x or y_idx != y:
                numspec[hab[x_idx][y_idx]] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap using `j%8` that gives you a number from 0 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a list of the adjacent elements and go from there. For example if your 2d list is called `my_array` and you wanted to examine the blocks immediately surrounding `my_array[x][y]` then you can do something like this:

```
xmax = len(my_array)
ymax = len(my_array[0])  #assuming it's a square...

x_vals = [i%xmax for i in [x-1,x,x+1]]
y_vals = [blah]

surrounding_blocks = [ 
     my_array[x_vals[0]][y_vals[0]],
     my_array[x_vals[0]][y_vals[1]],
     my_array[x_vals[0]][y_vals[2]],
     my_array[x_vals[2]][y_vals[0]],
     my_array[x_vals[2]][y_vals[1]],
     my_array[x_vals[2]][y_vals[2]],
     my_array[x_vals[1]][y_vals[0]],
     my_array[x_vals[1]][y_vals[2]],
        ]
```